# TypeError: utils.populate: invalid path. Expected string. Got typeof `undefined`

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use the `populate` [operator](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) of mongoose to merge a product and their users/owners.

I made a "exported" model of the product schema, specifying all fields like so:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const someSchema= new Schema({
  something1: String,
  customers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "customers" }],
  price: Number,
  ...
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("products", someSchema, "products");
```

I've managed to save the `_id` from the user/owner in the product and it appears orange as `"ObjectId('...')"` in MongoDB Compass and this same id matches with a user in the "customers" collection (looking manually).

But when I run the search in another module with:

```
  const model = require("../../models/productModel");
  model
    .populate("customers")
    .find({ < some fields> })
    .then( ... )
    .catch( ... )
```

It throws following error in the console:

```
TypeError: utils.populate: invalid path. Expected string. Got typeof `undefined`
```

Am I missing something here? I tried for almost an hour and got nothing. Sorry if I missed something crucial, I'm somewhat tired.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can also happen while passing empty object to `populate` instead of empty string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was that I called `populate` in the wrong order.

I was calling:

```
  model
    .populate("customers")
    .find({ < some fields> })
    .then( ... )
    .catch( ... )
```

But it **must** be in this order:

```
  model
    .find({ < some fields> })
    .populate("customers")
    .then( ... )
    .catch( ... )
```

Because we must first `find` the documents in order to `populate` them, otherwise it wouldn't make any sense.

Also for future reference, if you only specify `.populate("customers")`, it will not fill all ID fields *magically*, you must specify which field too. You do that with:

```
.populate({ path: "key_to_fill", model: "customers" })
```

And now it will replace `key_to_fill` with the document found in `customers`.

Other parameters and options you can find here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html (Official documentation)